# Find only renewed memberships

Tags: advanced-search

Is there a way in advanced search to only find members that have renewed their memberships?
It seems obvious but I can't find how :-(

best regards
Guillaume

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an Activity Type called Membership Renewal :-)

Not an obvious thing to search for but could do what you need

Comment: One could even set up a report that automatically mailed them a list of renewed members too!

Comment: Hi Pete! thanks for your answer. I